# ¿Como invocar un método en java a través de una variable String?

Tags: java

Tengo un menú para llamar todos los métodos (cada método es un ejercicio) de un trabajo que me dejaron en clase.

El switch para el menú lo tengo dentro de un "try" para manejo de excepciones, quiero que cuando salte el error lo devuelva al ejercicio (método) donde estaba, para eso lo que hago es guardar el una variable String el nombre del  ultimo método al que ingreso, pero no se como invocar el método desde una variable String. Básicamente es eso, ¿como invoco el método usado una variable?

El programa es algo asi:

```
public void menuPrincipal() {

    Data metodo = new Data();
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    int operacion = 0;
    String ultimo="";

    //menú que se muestra en pantalla

    System.out.print("\n  ->Seleccione la opcion deseada:  ");
    operacion = entrada.nextInt();

    try {
        switch (operacion) {
            case 1:
                ultimo="ejercicio73";
                metodo.ejercicio73();
                break;
            //...Aquí van el resto de opciones 
            default:
            System.out.println("Opcion fuera de rango");
            menuPrincipal();

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "El valor ingresado debe ser de tipo entero", "ADVERTENCIA", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        //Aquí quiero llamar llamar el ultimo método al que ingreso a usando la variable "ultimo"
    }
}
```

Por favor, ayúdenme

Answer (score 0):

se me ocurre que con if podrías validarlo, tipo:

```
if(ultimo.equals("ejercicio73")){
   metodo.ejercicio73();
}
```

Y pues para que no se te haga tan extenso, puedes hacer de todos esos if un método:

```
public void errorUltimo(String str){
   if(ultimo.equals("ejercicio73")){
       metodo.ejercicio73();
    }
    //aquí pones los demás if que sigan... 
}
```

Comment: Creo que lo que David nesecita es un do while centinela. ;-)

Comment: Pues no es mala idea eh, seria un poco extenso, pero dadas las circunstancias voy a hacerlo, y en lugar de guardar el ultimo metodo en un String, guardo el numero del ejercicio en un int, con eso uso un switch en lugar tantos if, Gracias

Comment: mira que es mejor idea que la mía, mételo a un método y solo llámalo para que no tengas que repetir tanto código

Comment: Tanto se utilice un if, un metodo aparte, un switch - Cuando ocurra un error se debera de comenzar. Al menos que utilizen un `goto` (xD) o recursividad lo mas facil seria un bucle centinela.

Comment: no se que sea un "goto", asi que no xd, pero un while con centinela, que buena idea, gracias <3